# ratio test to prove trigonometric series converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometric-series

I'm trying to convince myself that the following trigonometric series converges for all values of x

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{sin(nx)+cos(nx)}{n^2}$

my approach to the ratio test was following:

$\lim_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{\dfrac{sin(nx+x)+cos(nx+x)}{n^2(1+\dfrac{2}{n}+\dfrac{1}{n^2})}}{\dfrac{sin(nx)+cos(nx)}{n^2}}$

and I'm confused what to do next when I cancel $n^2$ terms and equate polynomials with $n$ in denominator to $0$.

Comment: Perhaps easier to note that $|\sin(nx) + \cos(nx)| \leq |\sin(nx)| + |\cos(nx)| \leq 1 + 1 = 2$.

Comment: Ratio test is a test for series with **nonnegative** terms. To test this one, maybe refer to those tests that applied to a series with terms in form of products.

Comment: A totally convergent series of continuous functions is a continuous function. For any $x$ and any $n$ we have $\left|\sin(nx)+\cos(nx)\right|\leq\sqrt{2}$.